# Scraping multiple pages gives empty dataframes

Tags: pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to combine two sets of coding I have in order to scrape info from multiple pages. My first block of code gets the URLs from a single page:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://betting.betfair.com/horse-racing/racecards/tomorrow/')

html =driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

url="https://betting.betfair.com"

data = []

alldata = soup.find_all(class_='racecard')

for item in alldata:
    racelinks = item.find_all('a')

    for a in racelinks:
        link = (a.get("href"))

        full_url = urljoin(url, link)
        print(full_url)

        driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()

        driver2.get(full_url)

        html2 =driver2.page_source
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
```

And then this code gets the info I am after:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://betting.betfair.com/horse-racing/racecards/03-december-2023/carlisle/7/1/')

html =driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

data = []

entries = soup.find_all(class_="race_entry")

for item in entries:
    for horse in item.find_all(class_='horse__name'):
        horse_name = horse.text.strip()

    for horse_info in item.find_all(class_='horse_extended'):
        li = item.find_all("li")
        rating = li[4].text.strip()
        rating_simple = rating.replace('OR: ', '')

    for tr in item.find_next('table').findAll('td')[0]:
        last_raced_on = tr

        from datetime import date
        from datetime import datetime

        today = date.today()

        date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

        date_today = datetime.today()

        date_last_race = datetime.strptime(last_raced_on,"%d/%m/%y")

        number_days_since_race = date_today-date_last_race

        number_days_since_race_simple = number_days_since_race.days

        data.append({
            "Horse": horse_name,
            "Official Rating": rating_simple,
            "Days Since Last Race": number_days_since_race_simple,
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

In the above code I have just used a random URL to make sure the info gets collected but in the real example I want the URL to be that of the scraped ones in the first line of code and for it to cycle over each URL.

I have tried this code:

```
alldata = soup.find_all(class_='racecard')

for item in alldata:
    racelinks = item.find_all('a')

    for a in racelinks:
        link = (a.get("href"))

        full_url = urljoin(url, link)

        driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()

        driver2.get(full_url)

        html2 =driver2.page_source
        
        soup2  = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(full_url).content, 'html.parser')


        entries = soup2.find_all(class_="race_entry")

        for item in full_url:

            for item in entries:
                for horse in item.find_all(class_='horse__name'):
                    horse_name = horse.text.strip()
```

Which opens all of the scraped URLs in Chrome but it doesn't scrape all the info and all I get is empty dataframes. I have tried to mess around with the positioning of the second code (not sure if it was in the wrong loop etc) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.